# Is it "no matter the occasion" or "no matter what the occasion"?

Tags: word-choice

Are both of the following correct?

> Look good no matter the occasion.

> Look good no matter what the occasion.

Comment: Googling "No matter the occasion" returns plenty of hits. It doesn't seem to have attracted any comments from linguists, however.

Comment: Curiously Google Ngram shows an strong increase in usage of “no matter what the occasion” in  recent decades https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+matter+the+occasion%2C+no+matter+what+the+occasion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20matter%20the%20occasion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20matter%20what%20the%20occasion%3B%2Cc0

Comment: They're both perfectly grammatical, as is "No matter what the occasion is". The two examples in your question are reduced interrogative clauses functioning as conditional adjuncts. You could also have "no matter what".

Comment: You can extend this form: *No matter the fruit*, wash, slice, and eat it fresh.

Comment: As usual, these are all shortenings of familiar sentences. How much of the sentence gets dropped depends on how familiar and how fast it is. The usual construction is _no matter {what/who/where/when/how Adj/ X is/was/has been, `S`_, where X is some noun phrase, and S is some assertion that is claimed to be true in all the specified contexts. Like _No matter how bad the weather is, you can count on Splash-Gard®_. This is gnawable down to _No matter how bad the weather_ or _No matter how bad it is_, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The most common word after *no matter the...* is in fact ***cost***, but it doesn't really make much difference which particular noun we look at - there's been [a significant usage shift](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no%20matter%20the%20cost%2Cno%20matter%20what%20the%20cost&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) in recent decades...

[image]

Personally, I think this is a completely "meaningless" stylistic choice - I'm not aware that either version is any more or less formal/informal than the other, nor do I think there's any slight nuance of *semantic* difference.

Before creating this chart, I might have guessed that discarding ***what*** here is a *slightly* "dated / literary" usage. But clearly that's not a tenable position. Use whichever version you like best.

---

Note you *must* include ***what*** when whatever follows is a *clause*, rather than a simple noun (or indeed, *nothing at all*, where some verb such as ***happens*** is implied)...

> 1: *Well, **I** like it, no matter what you think*
> 2: *I'll home in time for tea, no matter what [happens]*